# Date format conversion issue with NSDateFormatter

Tags: ios, date, nsdateformatter

I'm doing the following code:

```
NSString *stringToFormat = ticket.date;
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"dd MMMM yyyy"];

df.locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier: @"ro_RO"];
[df setDateFormat:@"dd.MM.yyyy"];
NSString *final = [df stringFromDate:[df dateFromString:stringToFormat]];
self.dateLabel.text = final;
```

The problem is that final is nil? Why?

Comment: what  ticket.date contains ?

Comment: The date in this format 16.Octombrie.2015 10:02

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two issues in your code:

1. You are using the same instance of date formatter with two different date format.
2. You have wrong date format set to fit your input date.

Here is corrected code:

```
NSString *stringToFormat = @"16.Octombrie.2015 10:02";

NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
df.locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier: @"ro_RO"];
[df setDateFormat:@"dd.MMMM.yyyy hh:mm"];

NSDateFormatter *df2 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
df2.locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier: @"ro_RO"];
[df2 setDateFormat:@"dd.MM.yyyy"];

NSString *final = [df2 stringFromDate:[df dateFromString:stringToFormat]];
```

You have to also set locale to first date formatter to let formatter recognise *Octombrie* as valid month.

Answer (score 1):

Please use this format for your ticket **dd.MMMM.yyyy hh:mm**

```
 NSString *stringToFormat = ticket.date;
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"dd.MMMM.yyyy hh:mm"];//16.Octombrie.2015 10:02
df.locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier: @"ro_RO"];

NSDateFormatter *localDF = [NSDateFormatter new];
localDF.locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier: @"ro_RO"];
[localDF setDateFormat:@"dd.MM.yyyy"];

NSString *final = [localDF stringFromDate:[df dateFromString:stringToFormat]];
```

Comment: @Spartanu13 Now please see my edited answer. Its working fine for me.

Comment: @Spartanu13 What you are getting ?

Comment: stil nil. But the problems were what @psci said. It's fixed now

Answer (score 0):

the format that you are receiving in ticket.date is not what you have given in the code.
"dd MMMM yyyy" <--- this is the format you gave in your code, but may not be the format which you are  receiving in ticket.date